# How to set Encoder.LuminanceTable when saving image to jpeg

Tags: c#, jpeg, system.drawing

I'm trying to manipulate advanced image params when saving image to jpeg.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(String mimeType = "image/jpeg")
    {
        int j;
        ImageCodecInfo[] encoders;
        encoders = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        for (j = 0; j < encoders.Length; ++j)
        {
            if (encoders[j].MimeType == mimeType)
                return encoders[j];
        }
        return null;
    }

...

        var img=Image.FromFile(
            @"myoriginal.jpg");
        ImageCodecInfo nfo = GetEncoderInfo();

        var eps = new EncoderParameters(2);
        eps.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.LuminanceTable, new byte[]
        {    2,   1,   1,   2,   2,   4,   5,   6, 
            1,   1,   1,   2,   3,   6,   6,   6, 
            1,   1,   2,   2,   4,   6,   7,   6, 
            1,   2,   2,   3,   5,   9,   8,   6, 
            2,   2,   4,   6,   7,  11,  10,   8, 
            2,   4,   6,   6,   8,  10,  11,   9, 
            5,   6,   8,   9,  10,  12,  12,  10, 
            7,   9,  10,  10,  11,  10,  10,  10  });
        eps.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.ChrominanceTable, new byte[]
        {    2,   2,   2,   5,  10,  10,  10,  10 ,
            2,   2,   3,   7,  10,  10,  10,  10, 
            2,   3,   6,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10, 
            5 ,  7,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10, 
            10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10, 
            10,  10,  10, 10,  10,  10,  10,  10, 
            10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10, 
            10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10 , 10,  10 });

        ImageCodecInfo ici = GetEncoderInfo();

        img.Save(@"changed.jpg",ici,eps);
```

When I run this, I get following error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Parameter is not valid.
```

How do I set LuminanceTable and ChrominanceTable?

Comment: Have you tried to use integer instead of bytes?